# How to install Telnet from a PowerShell Core prompt

Tags: telnet, powershell-core

To install Telnet in **PowerShell** you can run:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -name Telnet-Client
```

This unfortunately does not seem to work in **PowerShell Core** where it produces the following error:

```
Install-WindowsFeature : The term 'Install-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

What is the equivalent command in PowerShell Core to install Telnet?

Using Windows 10 version 2004, Insider Program

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run in an elevated shell:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "TelnetClient"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to install Telnet is via DISM:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

If neither PowerShell `Install-WindowsFeature` nor DISM work for you,
then Microsoft does not supply Telnet for your Windows version.

You could instead install
[Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)
and then install its package of
[telnet](https://push.chocolatey.org/packages/telnet)
using the command:

```
choco install telnet
```

Comment: I edited the question with the Windows version. DISM worked great on an elevated shell. I don't think it's necessary to use Chocolatey in this case being this a operating system feature that can be enabled/disabled.

Comment: Chocolatey is only for cases where this Windows feature doesn't exist.